# How to match response in one dataframe to value in other dataframe

Tags: r

I need some help with this:

I have a larger vector of predictions (v1) for around 20k people and a dataframe (df) with binary variables with the choices of the people for some options and I want to match the prediction with his suitable choice option, I'm using R in this case.

An example:

```
> v1 (vector with prediction for each person)
predict 
1 a 
2 b 
3 a 
4 c 
5 a

> df (matrix with response to each option for person)
  a b c d
1 0 0 0 0
2 1 1 0 1
3 0 0 1 0
4 1 0 1 0
5 0 1 1 1

> i want (the prediction for each person with the choice of the person for the predicted option):
  predict choice
1       a      0
2       b      1
3       a      0
4       c      1
5       a      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v1 <- c('a','b','a','c','a')
df <- dplyr::tribble(
  ~a, ~b, ~c, ~d,
  0,0,0,0,
  1,1,0,1,
  0,0,1,0,
  1,0,1,0,
  0,1,1,1)

choice <- purrr::map_dbl(1:nrow(df), function(i){
  df[i,][[v1[[i]]]] })

data.frame(predict=v1, choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for

Your data

```
v1 <- c("a","b","a","c","a")
names(v1) <- 1:5 

df <- read.table(text="a b c d
0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1
0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
0 1 1 1", header=TRUE)
```

Solution

```
library(purrr)
map_df(seq_along(v1), function(i) data.frame(person = names(v1)[i], 
                                predict = v1[i],
                                choice = df[names(v1)[i], v1[i]]))
```

Output

```
  person predict choice
1      1       a      0
2      2       b      1
3      3       a      0
4      4       c      1
5      5       a      0
```

Comment: this function pretty well for me, thanks. But when i have to apply this to a larger dataset was really slower.